# Firefox Install error ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

When I run the sudo apt-get install firefox to install firefox, install fails when connecting to us.archive.unbuntu.com. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: might be a temporary glitch in connectivity, if persistent, you could try to use a different archive (either remove the us country code in /etc/apt/sources.list or replace it with another country), then run 'apt-get update' and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the network with the proxy? in that case, you must export the proxy by

```
export http_proxy="http://<proxy>:<port>/"
export https_proxy="https://<proxy>:<port>/"
```

or edit the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf`  and add

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://<proxy>:<port>/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://<proxy>:<port>/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://<proxy>:<port>/";
```

if the proxy is not the problem change the server country and try again there may be a glitch in connectivity as @antonello said